# elif and functions python how to?

Tags: python, function, file

I have this code

```
elif device_type == "7":
print("\n")
print("************************************")
print("*****                          *****")
print("*****   Comparision Checker    *****")
print("*****    Of Two Configs        *****")
print("************************************")
print("\n")
print('\nWARNING: Discrepancies found:')

def open_file_and_return_list(file_path):
    list = []
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        line = f.readline()
        while line:
            list.append(line)
            line = f.readline()
    return list


def clean_new_line(list):
    for i in range(len(list)):
        if "\n" in list[i]:
            list[i] = list[i].replace("\n", "")
    return list


if __name__ == "__main__":
    list1 = open_file_and_return_list(r"new.txt")
    list2 = open_file_and_return_list(r"standard.txt")
    maxl = max(len(list1), len(list2))
    list1 += [''] * (maxl - len(list1))
    list2 += [''] * (maxl - len(list2))
    diff = []
    diff_file = input("\nINFO: Select what to name the difference(s) : ")
    open(diff_file, 'w').close()

    for iline, (l1, l2) in enumerate(zip(list1, list2)):
        if l1 != l2:
            print(iline, l1, l2)
            print(iline, l1, l2, file=open(diff_file, 'a'))
```

When I use option 7, I obviously get this error.

> INFO:  Select Test: 7
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:/Users/a/a/a/pre-post-check-LATEST.py", line 866, in
>
> ---
>
> list1 = open_file_and_return_list(r"new.txt")
>   *****                          *****
>    File "C:/Users/a/a/a/pre-post-check-LATEST.py", line 850, in open_file_and_return_list
>   *****   Comparision Checker    *****
>   *****    Of Two Configs        *****
>
> ---

How can I fix this issue, or obviously my logic is not right, how can i fix my logic?
Thanks

Comment: `elif` must follow an `if` statement. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm. You probably just want `if`.

Comment: That error message does not seem to contain the actual error.  Are you sure that's the whole message?

Answer (score 0):

*I didn't add the whole code*

So I was able to actually fix my own issue! I had a bunch of **if** statements and i broke them by putting **elif** above another **elif**.

Thanks again for letting me go over my code, I seem to have had my eyes glaze over. Thanks John Gordon and APhillips!